# QMake: Automatically compiling all files in a directory

Tags: qt, qmake

For my Qt project, I use a .pro file that includes a separate .pri file for the various header, source, form and resource files. However, every time I add a new file I need to manually add it to the .pri file. This is tedious and error-prone. Is there a way to "magically" add all files from a directory, either directly in the .pri file or by telling qmake to run a separate script beforehand?

Comment: Nice question! But... potential errors due to adding arbitrary files (from a directory) can be more than those when a file name is mistyped. Adding a file name to the .pri file takes much less time than adding a source file so this time should be neglected

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Running `qmake -project` will create a project file that includes all the `.cpp` and `.h` files in a directory, including subdirectories. You could add a pre-compile step that calls `qmake -project`, and only keep the part where the input files are defined. Here's a quick one-liner:

**Linux:**

```
qmake -project -o - | sed '1,/^# Input/d' > file_list.pri
```

**Windows:** (PowerShell command - only works with ASCII file and folder names due to various text encoding issues)

```
(qmake -project -o -) -ne "" -join "`r`n" -replace "(?s)^.*`r`n# Input`r`n", "" | Out-File -encoding ascii file_list.pri
```

Don't forget to `include(file_list.pri)` within your `.pro` file.

Answer (score 17):

You can use:

```
SOURCES += *.cpp
HEADERS += *.h
```

in your pro file. Of course you still have to remember to re-run qmake after creating new files.

Comment: How can you make this recursively add all source files in a given directory and all sub directories? This only adds the files in the root path.

Comment: Nor does it seem to work for any path except $$PWD, e.g. `../my_blah/*.h` doesn't work, it says "Failure to find..."