# qmake: Equivalent of INCLUDEPATH for source / cpp files?

Tags: c++, qt, build, qmake

Assume that we have a class called *Katze* in a directory called *dirOfKatze*.

Katze.h

```
#ifndef KATZE_H
#define KATZE_H


class Katze
{
public:
    Katze();
};

#endif // KATZE_H
```

Katze.cpp

```
#include "katze.h"
#include <iostream>

Katze::Katze()
{
    std::cout<<"MIAU"<<std::endl;
}
```

Lets assume that I want to add the class to a Qt project. I can do so by specifying

INCLUDEPATH += dirOfKatze

in my .pro file. Now the header file of Katze, or better all header files in the directory dirOfKatze are included. But unfortunately Katze.cpp can still not be found by the linker:

```
#include "katze.h"

int main()
{
    Katze myCat;

    return 0;
}
```

Results in: LNK2019 ...public: __cdecl Katze::Katze(void)"...

Is there any way to tell the linker that it should look for the cpp files in *dirOfKatze* equivalent to INCLUDEPATH? This relevant for me, because there might be many cpp files and I would like to add them all at once, without adding them one by one by typing SOURCE += .... \

Comment: Possible duplicate of [QMake: Automatically compiling all files in a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3806833/qmake-automatically-compiling-all-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the following lines in your .pro file:

```
HEADERS += pathTo_Katze.h
SOURCES += pathTo_Katze.cpp
```